# WPF: Creating attached bindable property

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add a property, that can be attached to any control and bind a value to it.

```
public class ValidationBorder : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "HasError",
                typeof(bool?),
                typeof(UIElement),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(Boolean))
            );

        public bool? HasError
        {
            get { return (bool?) GetValue(HasErrorProperty); }
            set {  SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value);}
        }

        public static void SetHasError(UIElement element, Boolean value)
        {
            element.SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value);
        }
        public static Boolean GetHasError(UIElement element)
        {
            return (Boolean)element.GetValue(HasErrorProperty);
        }
    }
```

My usage:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedFrequencyManual, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Center"
                         attached:ValidationBorder.HasError="{Binding Path=DataOutOfRange}">
                </TextBox>
```

When I start the project it displays error (translated):

> A Binding cannot be specified in the TextBox setHasError property.
>   Only a Binding can be specified in a DependencyProperty of a
>   DependencyObject

What can be wrong with it?

I've tried everything I could find on the web:

- Add parenthesis in the binding
- Add RelativeSource
- Change `DependencyProperty.Register` to `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`
- Different types for `typeof(UIElement)` including `typeof(TextBox)`

Comment: `typeof(UIElement)` is wrong, it should be `typeof(ValidationBorder)`

Comment: For *attached* property you use `RegisterAttached()` method [indeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this implementation:

```
public class ValidationBorder
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "HasError",
            typeof(bool?),
            typeof(ValidationBorder),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(bool?))
        );

    public static void SetHasError(UIElement element, bool? value)
    {
        element.SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value);
    }
    public static bool? GetHasError(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool?)element.GetValue(HasErrorProperty);
    }
}
```

You should call `RegisterAttached` and set the owner type to `ValidationBorder`. Also remove the `HasError` property. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview) for more information.